# the operator ^ is undefined for argument type(s) int,boolean

Tags: java, operator-precedence, boolean-operations

I am solving Hackerrank problem 'Maximizing xor'.
(https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/maximizing-xor)

I have used 'if' statement to check if i xor j is greater than 'max' as shown in code.

```
static int maxXor(int l, int r) {
    int max=0;
    for(int i=l;i<r;i++)
        for(int j=l;j<r;j++)
        {
            if(i^j>max)/*error part*/
            max=i^j;
        }
    return max;
}
```

But why am I getting this error?

> the operator ^ is undefined for argument type(s) int,boolean'

Comment: While other people have answered your question, please note that while this solution would pass it is not the most efficient solution. You can make it run faster if you try to think what XOR does on a bit level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put parentheses around the expression:

```
if ( (i ^ j) > max )
```

---

According to [Java's operator precedence table](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html), the XOR operator `^` has lower precedence than the inequality operator `>`.

Therefore your original written expression of `i ^ j > max` would be interpreted as `i ^ (j > max)`. But here, the types are incorrect: `i` is an `int`, but `(j > max)` is a `boolean`. That's why you got that compiler error.

---

As a side note, if you compiled this code in C/C++, it would have compiled but it would run with bizarre results. This is because in C/C++, the same operator precedence rules apply in this case, but the `bool` would be converted to an `int` of 0 or 1, and then the XOR would proceed. This would have been dangerous and wrong. The Java compiler stopped you from XORing an `int` with a `boolean`, which would be a nonsensical operation.

Comment: Yes, this is because `>` is evaluated before `^`. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at Java operator precedence: http://bmanolov.free.fr/javaoperators.php. As you can see, integer comparison (<, >) has greater precedence than xor. So your statement is interpreted in java as

```
if ( i ^ (j>max))
```

So you must manually add parens to your statement

```
if ( (i^j) > max)
```

in order to achieve your desired comparison.